# Does any (R)DBMS exist that supports Linked Lists?

Tags: database, linked-list

Are there any commercial databases that support data types pointing to the root node of say a linked list?

For example, I was thinking about the design for a basic ORDERS table (for an e-commerce site - say eBay or Amazon). In this case, a single order could contain multiple items and different quantities of each item. I thought I could represent this by having a linked list of items in the item column of the ORDERS table and a corresponding linked list for the quantity column.

So when total price of an order has to be established - simply multiply corresponding nodes of the linked lists and sum them up (of course you have a separate PRICE table that stores price of each item).

Comment: If you want to use SQL, you should start thinking in terms of relations, and don't try to directly map something like a linked list directly onto a relational data model.

Answer (score 0):

**Why** do you want to use a linked list for this?

Consider the following structure:

Table: ORDERS

- OrderID
- client, datestamp, status, ...

Table: ItemsInOrders

- ID
- REF_ORDER (FK OrderID)
- REF_Item (FK ItemID)
- Quantity

Table: Items

- ItemID
- Price
- Description, image, ...

Comment: Yes, I do realize that this is the other way to do it. But my question is - are more complex types like Linked Lists supported by commercial database vendors? I was specifically interested in knowing - if it is supported - how they implement removing a value from the list?

Answer (score 0):

Konerak gave the proper solution to this problem.

If you need a linked list in a database you basically need a purely object-oriented database or some mixed solution, like object types in Oracle. Then you can implement this yourself on the database side.